Base change along unramified extension of local fields
Let $E/F$ be a finite separable extension of local fields, and let $K$ be an $F$-algebra (in my case, an étale $F$-algebra). Let $O_K$ be the integral closure of $O_F$ in $K$. Consider the base change $L = E \otimes_F K$ of $K$ along $E/F$. Do we know that
$$O_L = O_E \otimes_{O_F} O_K?$$
Here, $O_L$ is the integral closure of $O_F$ in $L$.
The inclusion $O_E \otimes_{O_F} O_K \subseteq O_L$ is clear, and for equality, we need to show that $O_E \otimes_{O_F} O_K$ is integrally closed. I feel like there are some facts in the Stacks project that can prove this.

I assume that $E/F$ is unramified (the title mentions unramified extension), for ramified $E/F$ this is wrong. We may assume that $K$ is a finite separable extension of $F$ (because $K$ is a product of such and the integral closure in the product is the product of the integral closure and tensor product commutes with product). Let $\alpha\in O_E$ be such that it generates the residue field extension $k_E/k_F$ and let $g\in O_F[x]$ be its minimal polynomial. As $E/F$ is unramified, $\overline g$ is irreducible over $k_F$, so by the fact below $O_L=O_K[\alpha]$. Suppose $g$ factors as $g=\prod_i g_i$ (the $g_i$ being necessarily distinct irreducibles) over $K$. Then $L=\prod_iK[x]/(g_i)$ and $O_E\otimes_{O_F}O_K=\prod_iO_K[\alpha]/(g_i)$. It suffices to prove that each $O_K[x]/(g_i)$ is integrally closed. This is the case because of the fact below again.
Fact: Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, $g\in A[x]$ monic and irreducible such that $g$ is irreducible over the residue field. Then $A[x]/(g)$ is integrally closed. The proof is short, see for example this answer.
